# How to do Groupby , Sum, Avg ,Min, Max on java collections?

Tags: java, collections, guava

I have been trying to build a functionality which will enable me filter data in Java collections. The end goal is to have somethings as follow.

```
SomeBuilder(Collections)
.groupby("Key")
.filter("Key","Value")
.sum()
.getResult() ;
```

The functionality mostly resembles to sql world but not fully. My problem is how to filter collections like`List<HashMap<String,Object>`?

How can I apply groupby logic on such collections ?

A snippet of code showing filtering of such collection will help a lot. If Guava can do this please give an example.

Edit:- I have added an answer for this question but please suggest better ways of doing it. Hope this help others. For doing Sum ,Avg ,Count will update as I go ahead with my project.

Comment: the `groupBy == filter` ? And why do you have such kind of datastructure `List<HashMap<String,Object>` ? why not `Map<String, List>` or `MultiMap`. Map is "kind-of" groupby implementation (groupBy the key), isn't it?

Comment: Look at the Java 8 Stream API and its Collectors. FluentIterable from Guava can also do some of these things.

Comment: I am stuck with data structure and java version as 1.6 due to legacy reasons. Jdbc , if not use row mapper, gives us data in such format. there are other way but many of the engineers have used this data structure and then did a lot of manipulation over it. I want to insert a general mechanism which latter can be tweaked for performance. Can I change List<HashMap<String,Object> to multimap in guava. I tried it with less of luck (new to guava) ?

Comment: @EricBouweres Thanx for edit :). will keep in mind to format my questions from here onwards.

Comment: @Kent yes I would be looking at groupby as filter to reduce dataset on each step. In List<HashMap<String,Object>> each hashmap in the list will have key representing a database column name and value as the value of that column.  i.e each hashmap will have individual row data for the jdbc query .

Answer (score 0):

Ok This is to answer my own question and which may help others. I will be using the builder pattern to get the effect of method chaining. For filtering of

```
List<HashMap<String,Object>>
```

, I used Guava, here is an example of what I tried to do. Not the best way but a starter.

```
  private static Collection<HashMap<String, Object>>  filter(
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> resMap, final String key,
        final Object value) {
    Predicate<Map<String, Object>> keyValueMatch = new Predicate<Map<String, Object>>() {
        public boolean apply(Map<String, Object> stringStringMap) {
            return value.equals( stringStringMap.get(key));
        }
    };

    Collection<HashMap<String, Object>>  transformedList = Collections2.filter(resMap, keyValueMatch);
    return transformedList;
}
```

The usage will be as follow.

```
 Collection<HashMap<String, Object>>  transformedList =  filter(input,"Dep","GlobalWarming");
```

Hope this help. Any better suggestions are welcome.